# Link on banner image is not getting clicked in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a promotional banner on my site.

The HTML structure is something like this

```
<a href="#"><img src="#" usemap="abc"></img></a><map name="abc"><area ...></map>
```

Actual code:

```
<div id="promotion_banner" Style="position:fixed;right:0pt;top:25%;cursor: pointer;display:none;z-index:101;"> <a href="http://www.abc.com"> <img src="off-open-mar.png" alt="ABC" usemap="#hide_promo"></img> </a> <map name="hide_promo"> <area shape="rect" coords="20,235,42,260" id="hide_promotion" alt="text"> </map> </div>
```

When I click the banner in Chrome or FireFox or Opera or in any other browser except IE it is working fine.

But when I try the same thing in IE it is not clicking. On hover it is showing the appropriate URL but the URL is not clickable.
You can access the URL by doing a right click on the banner or by clicking the URL once and then hitting the enter.

If anyone knows something please let me know.

Comment: you dont need to close the img tag. scratch my previous comment.

Comment: does this work without the area and map?

Comment: did you also try the one on w3schools? does this work in your browser http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: paste the whole code here and mask the url

Comment: @btevfik i have tried many things. I have closed image tag and also unclosed them but still it is not working. And i tried the same as in w3schools, text is coming but it is not clickable.

Comment: so the one on w3schools is working fine? can you add you whole code in jsfiddle

Comment: @ka `<div id="promotion_banner" Style="position:fixed;right:0pt;top:25%;cursor: pointer;display:none;z-index:101;">`
    `<a href="http://www.abc.com">`
        `<img src="off-open-mar.png" alt="ABC" usemap="#hide_promo"></img>`
    `</a>`
    `<map name="hide_promo">`
          `<area shape="rect" coords="20,235,42,260" id="hide_promotion" alt="text">`
    `</map>`
`</div>`

Comment: @btevfik http://jsfiddle.net/jTSeY/

Comment: @Prateek hopefully my answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly in any browser:

```
<div id="promotion_banner"> 
<a href="2.html"> <img src="r.jpg" alt="ABC" usemap="#hide_promo" onclick="location.href='2.html'" style="cursor: hand;"/> </a> 
<map name="hide_promo"> 
    <area shape="rect" coords="20,235,42,260" id="hide_promotion" alt="text" /> 
</map> 
</div>
```

I had tested it in IE and it's working perfectly.
Since, Link on banner image is not getting clicked in IE due to compatibility issue, so I had called javascript onclick function:

```
 onclick="location.href='2.html'"
```

to make it clickable.

`Please note`: I had given URL deliberately in two places:

```
 (1)<a href="2.html"> 
 (2)"location.href='2.html'"
```

Because the **2nd one** `onclick="location.href='2.html'"` is supported and works well only in **IE**.

For all browsers (**chrome,safari,firefox,opera**) other than **IE**, the link on `<a href="2.html"><img...`     will work.

*Tricky solutions but works perfectly for any browsers.*